# Create HTML with JavaScript from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

As the title says, I am trying to write a function which would create some HTML based on the array I feed it.  If the array were simply one dimensional, I wouldn't have any problems.  But the "multidimensionality" of the array is where I'm having issues.  Namely since it's not always consistent.

I should also note that I am trying to accomplish this without any 3rd party JS libraries.

For example, here is a sample array:

```
var template = [
    ['div', {id: 'wrapper'}, [
        ['link', {rel:'stylesheet', href:'//mysite.com/css.css', type:'text/css'}],
        ['header', "Look at me!  I'm a header!"],
        ['nav', {class:'main-nav'}, [
            ['ul', [
                ['li', ['a', {'href':'/home'}, "Home"]],
                ['li', ['a', {'href':'/about'}, "About Us"]],
                ['li', ['a', {'href':'/erase_internet.php'}, "Don't click me!"]]
            ]]
        ]],
        ['section', "Some sample text!"],
        ['footer', "Copyright &copy; 1984"]
    ]]
];
```

The format of the array is:

`[string "type" [, json obj "attributes" ][, string "text"][, array "children"]]`

Now I already have one function which takes a single array object and creates an element:

```
function createEl(type, attr, text) {
    var key, el = d.createElement(type);

    if (typeof attr === 'object' && !Array.isArray(attr)) {
        for (key in attr) {
            if (attr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                el.setAttribute(key, attr[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (typeof attr === 'string' && text.length > 0) {
        el.appendChild(d.createTextNode(attr));
    }

    if (typeof text === 'string' && text.length > 0) {
        el.appendChild(d.createTextNode(text));
    }

    return el;
}
```

But I want to be able to process all of the "children" and append them to their parents, as indicated by the sample array, so that the output would look like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//mysite.com/css.css" type="text/css" />
    <header>Look at me!  I'm a header!</header>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/erase_internet.php">Don't click me!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>Some sample text!</section>
    <footer>Copyright &copy; 1984</footer>
</div>
```

**So here are my questions:**

1. If I don't know how many levels deep the array goes, what's the best-practice method for traversing through the `children` and all of the grand-`children`?
2. Would I call the `createEl()` function again from within itself to create and append those children elements, if they exist?

   - Is that even *possible?*
3. Would it help at all if I changed the structure of the array to this?:

   `[string "type" [, json obj "attributes" [, string "text" [, array "children"]]]]`
4. Is there maybe a better way of doing this altogether, without having to resort to jQuery or the like?  (subjective, but I value the expertise and experience of the SO Community)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel at least in templating case. Have a look at template plugins for JS

Comment: Also, this is a tiny pedantic comment but technically you should put `class` on line 5 of `template` in quotes because it is actually a reserved word in JS (sorry)

Comment: @redV - I didn't mention this in my question but this is sort of an exercise for me... Reinventing the wheel is kinda what I'm shooting for here. ;)

Comment: @user2521439 Agreed!  I don't actually have `class` in my code, but I did fail to encapsulate that in my example.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo That's ok :) Just saw it and made me think - I believe the `class` keyword is being implemented in ES6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will need to setup your createEl in a recursive fashion.  So, if you have deeper children, the function is triggered recursively for those children.
2. Yes, look at 1.
3. Your preference.
4. I don't think, but not sure, that jQuery would buy you anything in your case.  My suggestion is to look up how recursion works as an idea and apply it to JavaScript syntax.

[A good place to get started](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-lesson-205/0/1)

Comment: I'm going to check that out right now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Took me a minute to get my head wrapped around this, but once I did it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the steering me in the right direction!